# Why do I keep getting an infinite loop when using custom listener?

Tags: java, android, interface, adapter

I am working on an android app and I am implementing my own listener so my fragment can react when a spinner value is selected. The problem is that when I call the refresh method in my fragment, I keep getting an infinite loop.

**SpinnerAdapter:**

```
 public interface OnSpinnerItemSelectedListener {
        public void onSpinnerItemSelected(int index);
 }
 public SpinnerAdapter(Activity context, OnSpinnerItemSelectedListener listener){
    super(context)
    mListener = listener;
 }
 private OnSpinnerItemSelectedListener mListener;
 Spinner spinner;//Already initialized and contains values, but I didn't think it would be important to show that here.
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onSpinnerItemSelected(i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

**Fragment Adapter Initialization:**

```
SpinnerAdapter adapter =  new SpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), new  SpinnerAdapter.OnSpinnerItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpinnerItemSelected(int index) {
                refreash(SpinnerFragment.this,getActivity());
            }
        });//calls the refresh method infinite number of times.
```

**Refresh Method**

```
    //the problem isn't the implementation, its just that interface keeps calling it repeatedly. 
 public void refreash(Fragment f,Context activity) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,f).commit();
    }
```

Comment: Include the code for `refreash()`.

Comment: Actually we can't help you out if you don't provide the code that is causing the problem...

Comment: I am pretty sure its not the refresh fragment. It keeps getting called multiple times. I will post it now.

Comment: I think Spinner.setAdapter() will call onItemSelected method , may be it causes the infinit loop. Where is setAdapter calling in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error might be in your `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method. Since you have the sensation it's an infinite loop when you're actually calling `commit()` on the `FragmentManager`, it probably happens because your `onCreateView()` is being called on an already created `Fragment`, so you're trying to redefine the layout.

Your `onCreateView()` method should look like this:

```
// This variable is class-wide  
View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (view != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null)
      parent.removeView(view);
  }

  // Do whatever you need to do, but begin inflating your layout.
  // in this example it's a LinearLayout
  view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

  ...
}
```